# Why is Kafka Streams TopologyTestDriver so slow? How can we speed it up?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We make Kafka Streams apps that have complicated topologies for data integration pipelines. We love using the Kafka Streams TopologyTestDriver in a Test Driven Development fashion to develop our topologies.

However, the slowness of the TopologyTestDriver is getting in the way of development velocity. It seems that `TestInputTopic.pipeInput(...)` is the bottleneck.

Why do TopologyTestDriver tests run so slowly? Can we do anything to speed up our TopologyTestDriver tests?

##### 2022-12-02 Update:

Clue to the puzzle: this slowness is experienced on our MacBooks. Our suite takes 700 seconds on the MacBooks and 70 seconds on our linux Jenkins servers.

Comment: Slow compared to what? You could use TestContainers / EmbeddedKafka to run an actual broker, but I bet that'll be even slower.

Comment: These testing tools aren't very optimized and aren't tested for performance regressions. That being said, AK itself uses the `TopologyTestDriver` a lot in its tests, and it would probably be noticed if it was prohibitively slow. Have you tried hooking up a profiler to your tests and find the hotspots? Maybe there is an opportunity here to contribute back to Kafka.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Relatively slow, compared to nothing in particular. It takes anywhere between 1 to 5 seconds to return from `pipeInput`.

Comment: @LucasBrutschy We're using this for functional testing, not performance testing, and in this functional context it does feel prohibitively slow (1 to 5 seconds per pipeInput invocation). Thanks for the heads on Apache using the TopologyTestDriver on their own stuff -- I didn't think about this. I can browse that to see if they are configuring something special. We've profiled, and certainly pipeInput is the slow part, but I can't make sense of what is going on inside of pipeInput to figure out how to speed it up.

Comment: So I can run a test with 5 `pipeInput` invocations in 800ms on my Mac. Note that `pipeInput` actually executes your business logic, so it may be related to what precisely the topology that you are testing is doing.

Comment: True, we have large, complex topologies - but it's the same topology running through the TopologyTestDriver that runs at different speeds on different machines. I can't point to anything specific, but I suspect it has something to do with the Test Driver's internal mock wall clock and time advancement.